# PSLG to polyhedral complex

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, polyhedra

We have a PSLG whose outer face is a triangle and the other faces could either be a triangle or a quadrilateral. We are given the half-edges to walk through the PSLG. What is an efficient algorithm that requires the least number of changes to convert the PSLG into a polyhedral complex?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you edit the question to include some code?

Comment: i do not know where to start. Any pointers/

Comment: The thing is, SO is a site for specific programming questions, in the style of "I used X to do Y, but instead of the expected result Z, I got this error; see the relevant part of my code and the error message below." Wide or vague questions like "I want to do X but I don't know where to start" are unlikely to get any (good) answers. It may work, if other people find the question interesting enough, but you run the risk of having your question closed for being "too vague".